# Is not uploading and update the image into database

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User\Profile;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Countries;
use Auth;
use Hash;
use File;
 
class UserprofileController extends Controller
{
   public function profile(){
   
    if(Auth::check()){
      $user = User::get();
      $data['users'] = $user;
      $country = Countries::all();
      $data['countries'] = $country;
      return view ('user.profile.userprofile') -> with($data);
      }
      else{
       return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'You are not login..');
       }
      }
     public function profilesetup(Request $request){

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);

    $user->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
    $user->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $user->country = $request->input('country');
    $user->timezone = $request->input('timezone');

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        $destination = 'uploads/profile/'.$user->image;
        if(File::exists($destination)){
            File::delete($destination);
        }
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/profile/' , $filename);
        $user->image = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }
   
    $user->update(); 
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Profile Updated');

 }
 }
```

please tell me any proper code to update into the database. Is not uploading and update the image into the database. This is my controller page. what should I do to update the image into the database but first name and last name was updating to the database except image is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem your codebase may be working fine, though my problem was this part of the code:

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'yourfilename.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

Check if you have a defined form to handle the routes for storing the required image in your database.